# Group rows per date, calendar table used

Tags: mysql, sql

Following table:

```
members
-----------------------------------------------
id      name        created_at
-----------------------------------------------
1       John        2014-05-08 10:18:12
2       Josh        2014-05-07 10:10:36
3       Mark        2014-04-30 12:10:04
```

calendar:

```
-----------------------------------------------
calendar_date
-----------------------------------------------
1970-01-01
1970-01-02
...
2014-05-07
2014-05-08
2014-05-09
...
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  calendar.calendar_date,
  COUNT(members.id)
FROM
  calendar
LEFT JOIN
  members
    ON  DATE(members.created_at) >= calendar.calendar_date
    AND DATE(members.created_at) <  calendar.calendar_date + 1
WHERE
      calendar.calendar_date >= '2014-05-01'
  AND calendar.calendar_date <  '2014-05-20'
GROUP BY
  calendar.calendar_date
```

[image]

which is wrong.The dates 07-08 should only have count 1. Rest should be 0.

Whats wrong with my query?

Comment: Yjou use left outer join, so the row with date 2014-05-07 from table calendare  are two times in the join table, because the member table has two records witch match the where condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
LEFT JOIN
  members
    ON  DATE(members.created_at) >= calendar.calendar_date
    AND DATE(members.created_at) <  calendar.calendar_date + 1
```

write

```
LEFT JOIN
  members
    ON  DATE(members.created_at) = DATE(calendar.calendar_date)
```

because your `calendar.calendar_date` field is datetime field and should be truncated to date value only too.

Or to be absolutely sure, you can also do like this:

```
LEFT JOIN
  members
    ON DATE_FORMAT(members.created_at, '%Y%m%d') =
       DATE_FORMAT(calendar.calendar_date, '%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: You're overcomplicating. Simply `DATE(members.created_at) = DATE(calendar.calendar_date)`

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Thanks, I complicate things I know :)

Comment: When I try query a week, YEARWEEK(calendar.calendar_date, 1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(), 1)

It only gives me one result for wednesday, when thursday should have too.

Comment: I'm not sure what `yearweek` have to do with wednesday or thursday